# convert string to stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, stream

I'm trying to return a large .csv file as an action result using the Controller.File method, and it requires that I use either a `byte[]` or a Stream.

When using `GetBytes` method, I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Is there any way to do this without trying to put it all in memory at the same time?

Here's the return I'm using at the moment:

```
string csv = data.ToCsv();
return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "ClusterFMCacheExport.csv");
```

Comment: Show your code here.. People can't read your mind..

Comment: "a large .csv file" on disk?

Comment: I'm building the string and then trying to return it as a csv file.

Comment: don't yout need something like 
File.OpenRead(file) 
or new StreamReader(file)

Comment: I'm not opening a file.

Comment: data is the raw data that ToCsv() is building the lines of the string from.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not getting an `OutOfMemoryException` on `ToCSV()`?

Comment: Yes i separated the GetBytes part to make sure before posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return File(stream, "text/csv", "ClusterFMCacheExport.csv");
}
```

If your data is really *that* big, this might not help. If your generating a *very* large csv files, I suggest you re-write the `ToCsv()` generate a `stream` rather than a `string`.

Comment: @user2081737 honestly, I didn't expect it to. I figured you'd have to rewrite `ToCsv`. Glad to help.

Comment: I think I might, anyway.  It still took a long time.

Answer (score 0):

haven't used ASP.NET for some time, but shouldn't something like this work (assuming that file is on disk already):

```
FileStream fs = ... // stream over your csv file, however you get it
return File(fs, "application/csv", "file.csv");
```

Comment: Read the string into a MemoryStream

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.csv");
return Content(csv, "application/csv");
```

avoid the conversion? It might just kick it down the road though, only for the OOME to re-emerge elsewhere.