# How can I upload a CSV file as a stream using HttpClient as a body parameter?

Tags: c#, stream, httpclient

I was trying to convert csv file to contentStream with below code.

```
private const string ResourceFolder = "TestData\\";
private HttpContent _form;

      public void SendFile(string resource, string fileName)
    {
        _form = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)
            ? _form = new StringContent(string.Empty)
            : _form = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead($"{ResourceFolder}{fileName}"));

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
           content.Add(_form);
        _form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csv");

        WhenThePostRequestExecutesWithContent(resource, content);

    }

    public async void WhenThePostRequestExecutesWithContent(string resource, HttpContent content)
    {
        ResponseMessage = await HttpClient.PostAsync(resource, content);
    }
```

I am using `.Net core 2.1` and it gives below error in the last line in `File` location

The problem is I still find null for the below controller file parameter,

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SeedData(IFormFile file)
{
    var result = await _seedDataService.SeedData(file);
    return Ok(new { IsUploadSuccesful = result});
}
```

Comment: The compiler resolves `File` to `System.IO.File` because no overload of the `File` method matches your arguments (`Stream, string, Stream`). Why do you think you need a `MemoryStream` at all, here?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I need to add this stream to the httpclient body in my subsequent call

Comment: Any reason you can't just stream the CSV file directly? `File($"{ResourceFolder}{fileName}", "text/csv")` should suffice. The code you have now isn't actually doing anything with the memory stream. If you want to read the file into a stream for additional processing, you'll need more code than you have now (and then you can just return the `MemoryStream`).

Comment: @SMPH that error has nothing to do with streams. It means you're trying to use a `Controller` method outside the controller. In a controller action, the only thing you need to do to return a file stored on disk is `return File(pathToFile);`.

Comment: @SMPH Have you declared a field named `File` in your class?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I haven't.

Comment: @SMPH post the rest of your code then. [ControllerBase.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is a valid method. You can just use `return File(someFolder, "text/csv");` in a controller action to return a file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Basically I wanted to add `csv` file as a memory stream to the body of a httpClient post call in my tests. With the above I was trying to do that by following this solution. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526507/convert-string-to-stream `. Perhaps I don't have to do this. Could you propose any better solution?

Comment: @SMPH HttpClient is a completely different library. There are a lot of duplicate SO questions that show how you can post or upload a file using HttpClient. The code you used generates *results* for MVC controllers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated the question with underline code.

Comment: @SMPH you can't just copy code and hope it works. It's not just that you don't need that stream. `StreamContent` accepts any stream. You can open a FileStream with a simple `File.OpenRead()`. You've used `"application/json"` as the content type for a *CSV* file.

Comment: @panagiotis, Corrected the code to csv, Soy that was a typo. BTW API controller expect file as a body parameter. In my code streamContent worked but in the parameter file shows as null

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the code as suggested in the question to be more clear and still the empty file parameter in the controller is bothering me.

Comment: Check this issue [C#: Posting Model from body and file as MultipartFormDataContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209852/c-posting-model-from-body-and-file-as-multipartformdatacontent/52214628#52214628)

Comment: ffs please don't use `async void` anywhere exception on Windows Forms and WPF UI handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's contribution, Below code solved the problem.

```
private const string ResourceFolder = "TestData\\";
private HttpContent _form;

     public void AttachedRatesFile(string fileName)
        {
            _form = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)
                ? _form = new StringContent(string.Empty)
                : _form = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead($"{ResourceFolder}{fileName}"));

            _content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            _content.Add(_form, "file", fileName);
            _form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        }


    public async void WhenThePostRequestExecutesWithContent(string resource, HttpContent content)
    {
        ResponseMessage = await HttpClient.PostAsync(resource, content);
    }
```